# Rabbitmq commands are not working

Tags: python, unix, rabbitmq

When I perform `sudo rabbitmqctl add_user james mypassword` it returns:

```
Creating user "james" ...
Error: {badarg,
           [{erlang,group_leader,[undefined,<5490.18387.0>],[]},
            {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,99}]},
            {rabbit_auth_backend_internal,add_user,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_internal.erl"},{line,149}]},
            {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]}
```

I previously did not have a problem with this. However it has recently spawned this error and I'm not sure why. It also returns the same error when I try `sudo rabbitmqctl stop`:

```
Stopping and halting node rabbit@postr ...
Error: {badarg,[{erlang,group_leader,[undefined,<5490.18408.0>],[]},
                {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,99}]},
                {rabbit,'-stop_and_halt/0-after$^0/0-0-',0,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,387}]},
                {rabbit,stop_and_halt,0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,384}]},
                {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                     [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]}
```

My rabbitmq log file looks like this:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 1-May-2018::21:48:06 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.14307.0> (174.824.62.219:39718 -> 174.824.62.219:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'james' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}
```

However the user `james` doesn't exist now, `sudo rabbitmqctl list_users` returns:

```
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
```

I've tried changing my `CELERY_BROKER_URL` from `'amqp://{}:{}@174.824.62.219/vhost'.format(config('RABBIT_USER'), config('RABBIT_PW'))` to `'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'` - however still getting the same error.

Any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT**

I've also tried `service rabbitmq-server start` (to restart rabbitmq), and it returns:

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service` returns:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-03 07:30:37 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 29946 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8566 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8565 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Output of:

```
(env) james@postr:~/postr$ sudo netstat -plant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1403/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8409/postgres   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4690/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10518/beam      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4690/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30095/epmd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51656         127.0.0.1:4369          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:4369          127.0.0.1:35352         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0    332 174.824.62.219:22       49.194.155.110:49861    ESTABLISHED 5856/sshd: james [p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59810         127.0.0.1:4369          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56945         127.0.1.1:25672         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4369          127.0.0.1:41000         ESTABLISHED 30095/epmd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41000         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED 10518/beam      
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:4369          127.0.0.1:51514         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:4369          127.0.0.1:48547         TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57392         127.0.0.1:4369          TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1403/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      10518/beam      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4690/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      30095/epmd
```

Comment: This can happen if the hostname of the machine was changed recently. What is the output of "journalctl -u rabbitmq-server"?

Comment: `journalctl -u rabbitmq-server` returns `-- No entries --`

Comment: Run this `/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server` in terminal and see what error you get?

Comment: `sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server` returns `ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "postr"`

Comment: Restart you machine and try again and also add output of `sudo netstat -plant`

Comment: Ive restarted my machine: `sudo /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server` returns the same error as before - and I've added the output to `sudo netstat -plant` in my edit. Any clues to the problem in the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170365/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-zorgan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like took a 512MB RAM VM on the cloud which is too low for RabbitMQ to work. You should take at least 1GB and recommended is 2GB.

Take a new machine and then all should work